# Mounting /dev/sdd1 fails: according to mtab, /dev/sdd1 is already mounted

Tags: mount, fstab

Trying to mount drive but get an error

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdd1 is already mounted on /
mount failed
```

According to 'help answers I need to edit fstab mtab but where are these files located? Are NOT under etc unless 'hidden'?  Am novice to Ubuntu...

Comment: do a `more /etc/fstab` please. fstab has to be on your system. Keep away from editing /etc/mtab: this one is generated by your system. Add in both contents of `more /etc/ftsab` and `more /etc/mtab` into your question to get more accurare answers.

Answer (score 3):

This is the file you need to add devices that should be mounted on startup and no there is no reason for these 2 to be not on your system:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ ls /etc/fstab 
/etc/fstab
```

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ ls /etc/mtab
/etc/mtab
```

These files are not hidden and have to be on your system in order to boot.

- /etc/mtab is generated by the system so you do not need to edit this.
- [/etc/fstab](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) (link opens man page) you can edit yourself.

Mine looks like this:

```
rinzwind@discworld:~$ more /etc/fstab

# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=95a95954-0159-4a36-9a72-8b30b76283d2 /               ext4    errors=remount
-ro 0       1
# /discworld was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=bb498131-d803-4a57-97c8-98f9f01a8364 /discworld      ext4    defaults      
  0       2
# /discworld2 was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=b968131f-53d0-408c-8d66-7f429d73fb26 /discworld2     ext4    defaults      
  0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=82f7974a-7c77-4a1e-a494-5ee32f622697 /home           ext4    defaults      
  0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=a81a9a09-862d-4c5a-9baa-fb6a01eaf284 none            swap    sw            
  0       0
```

You need to find the UUID (look at the comments at the beginning of fstab. You also need to know some other things but you can find these by typing `more /etc/mtab | grep sdd1` Write down what is says there: you need that for editing `/etc/fstab`. Editing system files requires the usage of sudo. I would also **strongly** advice making a backup 1st like so:

`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.20110521`

You can edit fstab with:

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

But be sure to use tabs where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in pcmanfm, when you have multiple mounting(for example after chroot or pivot_root), it will show not mounted disk.

For example, "udisks --dump" shows:

```
Showing information for /org/freedesktop/UDisks/devices/sda4
...
mount paths:            /old_root/media/malcolm/DOC,/media/malcolm/DOC
```

After i do "sudo umount /old_root/media/malcolm/DOC", pcmanfm will show mounted "DOC" disk.